# Field order on #region IBinarySerialize

Tags: c#, sql-server, serialization, sqlclr, user-defined-aggregate

I created `IBinarySerialize` region in order to create my CLR for my user defined aggregate.  I am trying to replicate my XIRR function in C# just to learn how to work with CLRs.  I put Write and Read in the same order but when I tried to build I get Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime' to
>   'bool'    CustomAggregates    D:\Transfer\CustomSqlAggregates\CustomAggregates\XIRR.cs    255 Active

The error is coming in from the write section.

I can't seem to find what I am missing in this arrangement following some examples that I have seen in examples.
Here is the get/set for the struct

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.Native,
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false, // Receiving the same value again changes the result
    IsInvariantToNulls = false,      // Receiving a NULL value changes the result
    IsInvariantToOrder = true,      // The order of the values affects the result
    IsNullIfEmpty = true,            // If no values are given the result is null
    MaxByteSize = -1,                // Maximum size of the aggregate instance. -1 represents a value larger than 8000 bytes, up to 2 gigabytes
    Name = "XIRR"             // Name of the aggregate
    )]
public struct XIRR : IBinarySerialize
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to store the product
    /// </summary>
    public SqlDouble Result { get; private set; }
    public SqlDouble Cashflow { get; private set; }
    public SqlDateTime CashflowDateTime { get; private set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }
    public List<CashItem> CashFlows { get; private set;}

    ...

    #region IBinarySerialize
    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the values to the stream in order to be stored
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="write">The BinaryWriter stream</param>
    public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter write)
    {
        write.Write(Result);
        write.Write(Cashflow); //Line - 255
        write.Write(CashflowDateTime);
        write.Write(HasValue);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the values from the stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="read">The BinaryReader stream</param>
    public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader read)
    {
        Result = new SqlDouble(read.ReadDouble());
        Cashflow = new SqlDouble(read.ReadDouble());
        CashflowDateTime = new SqlDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(read.ReadString()));
        HasValue = read.ReadBoolean();
    }
    #endregion IBinarySerialize
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if you want me to provide further information.

Comment: Please show the declaration of CashFlowDateTime with its datatypen also please point out line 255 from D:\Transfer\CustomSqlAggregates\CustomAggregates\XIRR.cs

Comment: By the way, style guides almost unanimously recommend not using regions.  They were invented for one specific purpose - hiding designer code in .net 1.0 winforms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a mismatch in your types. What are the exact types of `Result`, `Cashflow`, and `CashflowDateTime`? According to the `Read` method they are `Sql*` types. Is that really how they are declared? Or are they declared as `Double` and `DateTime`?

At the very least I think you are handling the `CashflowDateTime` incorrectly in both directions. Assuming that `CashflowDateTime` is truly a `SqlDateTime`, then I am guessing that you might need to replace this line in the `Write` method:

```cs
write.Write(CashflowDateTime);
```

with the following two lines:

```cs
write.Write(CashflowDateTime.DayTicks);
write.Write(CashflowDateTime.TimeTicks);
```

And then, replace this line in the `Read` method:

```cs
CashflowDateTime = new SqlDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(read.ReadString()));
```

with the following (which reconstructs the `SqlDateTime` from the "DayTicks" and "TimeTicks" values):

```cs
CashflowDateTime = new SqlDateTime(read.ReadInt32(), read.ReadInt32());
```

Also:

1. The `#region IBinarySerialize` doesn't do anything functional here. Removing that would not affect the code.
2. For more info on working with SQLCLR, please see: [SQLCLR Info](https://SQLCLR.org/)

Comment: I have IBinarySerialize during the creation of the struct. SQL Server is throwing an error saying it is expecting Serialized in the code. I get the same error for first 3 of them.
public struct XIRR : IBinarySerialize
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to store the product
    /// </summary>
    public SqlDouble Result { get; private set; }
    public SqlDouble Cashflow { get; private set; }
    public SqlDateTime CashflowDateTime { get; private set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }
    public List<CashItem> CashFlows { get; private set;}

Comment: sorry I don't know how to property format in the comment. Thanks for your help in advance.  My C# is still very weak and I have been using posted examples online to work on this CLR.

Comment: @WinstonKyu Please add what you have in the first comment into the exist example code in the question, including whatever decorators (e.g. `[Serializable]`, `[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(...)]` )you have just above the `public struct XIRR...` line. Thanks. Also, regarding formatting, when you are typing in a comment, there is a "help" link-button to the right of the comment text area. It will expand to provide some basic info with links to more detailed info.

Comment: sorry for the delay.  I added the beginning get/set to the code. If I remove IBinarySerialize from my struct, my C# code compiles fine but it errors out on SQL Server when I try to assign it to the aggregate function.

Comment: @WinstonKyu Thanks for adding that info. We still need the decorators (e.g. `[Serializable]`, `[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(...)]` ). Also, why are you using `struct` instead of `class`? Using `struct` I believe requires setting another option somewhere about field order or something like that.

Comment: I have been sampling from CLR codes that I found to write up the code and they all use struct.  I added the summary up top.